# From a list with lists, I need to manipulate the elements and build another list with lists

Tags: python

I need, from a list with lists inside, to multiply each element by 2. So creating 3 new lists inside another list.

```
listao = [['lista1', 'agora', 'fui', 'a1'], 
          ['lista2', '10', '30', 'v'], 
          ['lista3', '5', '4', 'a3']]
```

output:

```
[['lista1', 'agora', 'fui', 'a1'],
 ['lista2', '10', '30', 'v'],
 ['lista3', '5', '4', 'a3']]
```

I'm using this code:

In this code I have the result of the multiplication, but I don't know how to make the lists separate.

```
novalista = []

for i in listao:
  for j in i:
    x = j*2
    novalista.append(x)
```

output:

```
['lista1lista1', 'agoraagora', 'fuifui', 'a1a1', 'lista2lista2', '1010', '3030', 'vv', 'lista3lista3', '55', '44', 'a3a3']
```

But I need this result:

```
[['lista1lista1', 'agoraagora', 'fuifui', 'a1a1'],
 ['lista2lista2', '1010', '3030', 'vv'],
 ['lista3lista3', '55', '44', 'a3a3']]
```

Comment: try this `for i in listao:`
          ` temp = []`
              ` for j in i:`
                  ` x = j*2`
                   `temp.append(x)`
               `novalista.append(temp)`

Comment: `[[val * 2 for val in lst] for lst in listao]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
novalista = []

for i in range(len(listao)):
    novalista.append([])
    for j in listao[i]:
        x = j * 2
        novalista[i].append(x)
```

I changed it so that you append a list every time you transition from one list to another in the `listao` variable

That should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
[[item * 2 for item in sublist] for sublist in listao]
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 ['lista1lista1', 'agoraagora', 'fuifui', 'a1a1'],
 ['lista2lista2', '1010', '3030', 'vv'],
 ['lista3lista3', '55', '44', 'a3a3']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

an lol to the question, another one to the first comment as well.. the list comes from Brazil, obviously. but anyways.

Not sure what the intent is, but the most important aspect you need to understand is what you are looping over.

The outer for (for i in listao) you are looping over each list contained in listao.
The inner for (for j in i) you are looping over each item within each list contained in listao.

So if we translate the code written to meaningful english, it says 'loop over each list, on each list loop over each item, multiply that by 2 and append it to this list.'

Similar to the previous answer, but not quite (in my view), you need to add a sub element in your loop such that you append that sub element instead of each item to the main list.

```
new_listao = []
for item in listao:
    sub_list = []
    for element in item:
        sub_list.append(element*2)
    new_listao.append(sub_list)
```

there is probably a more pythonic way of handling this in a list comprehension (read about this if you havent) but it will take some thought if it is worth it. See mechanic pig's comment.